# Ajax Not Load my other External js Files How To Do It

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#livesearch").on("keyup",function(){
        var search_term = $(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax-live-search.php",
            type:"POST",
            data: {livesearch:search_term},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#show-search").html(data);
            }
           
        });

        
    }); 
});
```

My other Js files are not run on jquery ajax function i want to load my MAIN js file to this ajax function how to do it

Comment: AJAX is not a good way to load JavaScript. If the other JS files are local, you can call them using the `<script>` tag in HTML. Otherwise you can look at JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code. It is a jQuery code that is used to perform an AJAX call when the keyup event is triggered on an element with the ID of "livesearch". The AJAX call sends the value of the element to the "ajax-live-search.php" file and the response is then displayed in an element with the ID of "show-search".